# Open an iOS app in the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator

I built an web-based app, ran it through PhoneGap, which gave me an .ipa file. Now I want to create screenshots using the iPhone Simulator. But I can't figure out any way to get the app into the simulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy your PhoneGap app through XCode to the simulator.

Comment: But how? I've added the app to a device (iPhone 5), but I also need screenshots for iPhone 4(s) and iPad.

Comment: After you install PhoneGap it adds a project template (PhoneGap-based Application) to XCode. You can then add your web app files to it, and run as if it were a native app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It'll be ARM code which it can't read. See:

[How can I install a .ipa file to my iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator)

PhoneGap must have other ways to run it in the simulator?