# Installing .ipa into iPhone simulator

Tags: ios-simulator

I have a .ipa file which I want to install into iPhone simulator. I am trying this in a MAC m/c running OS X 10.7 version. Please help me on how to install the .ipa into iPhone simulator.

Thanks,
Sitam

Answer (score -4):

I found an .ipa file that I wanted using iTunes and copied it over to my desktop.

After that I changed the extension to .zip and extracted it.

Next I found the Payload folder and moved the application inside to my desktop.

Finally I moved that application to my iPhone simulators applications folder found at:

"Your disk name">Developer>Platforms>iPhoneSimulator.platform>Developer>SDKs>
iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk>Applications
Hope this helps!(Note: Some apps crash more often than others)

Comment: You will better post the source of the answer rather than taking credits for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9385507/2604030

Comment: that solution is too old, i really don't know if it works, do you try it before copying and pasting ?