# how to install an IPA on ios 7.0 simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, simulator, ipa

i am using xcode 5.0 and i want install an ios application to my ios simulator to test and research. I had searched in google and i found some solution but it did't work. Some body helps me. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a .ipa file to my iPhone simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to install an IPA on the simulator. The IPA has been compiled for the ARM CPU in the iPad/iPhone/iPod. See this for more info [How can I install a .ipa file to my iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator)

However, if you have the source code and are building the app you can simply deploy to the simulator. In the top left of XCode you will be able to select the build target (iPad Retina, iPad etc along with iOS Version). If you set that to the appropriate simulator type and select run then it will build and deploy a version that is compatible with the simulator.