# Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get this error only, when I use bundled js.Before bundled app works properly ,used react native version is 0.19.How to remove this error while bundled please help me

> The screen shot is attached below
>   [image]

Comment: Are you on iOS or Android ?

Comment: not following the answer. what did you do to get pass this error?

Comment: I have the same problem here, not only when bundling.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ensure that your AppDelegate.m file is not registering the React URL as pointing to disk. In 0.19, no on-disk bundle is created when deploying to the simulator. It must fetch the bundle over localhost or another IP.

Comment: So We cant test Release build on Simulator?

Comment: It is an iOS simulator rather than an emulator, and cannot run the ARM CPU instructions used to build a release build for the iTunes store. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator