# React native bug RCTFatal

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, native

What can be wrong here?

```
Failed to call function, __fbBatchedBridge is undefined

RCTFatal
-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]
__21-[RCTCxxBridge start]_block_invoke
invocation function for block in facebook::react::(anonymous namespace)::RCTObjcExecutor::RCTObjcExecutor(id<RCTJavaScriptExecutor>, void (NSError*) block_pointer, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::MessageQueueThread>, std::__1<facebook::react::ExecutorDelegate>)
__58-[RCTWebSocketExecutor _executeJSCall:arguments:callback:]_block_invoke
-[RCTWebSocketExecutor webSocket:didReceiveMessage:]
__33-[RCTSRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
_dispatch_lane_invoke
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

I am trying tu build react native app on osx device in emulator.

`npm run ios`

Comment: Hi interesting, I wonder if this might be of interest https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6282

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877093/react-native-unable-to-execute-js-call-fbbatchedbridge-is-undefined