# Are there any emulators that run ipa (ios) files on either windows or mac?

Tags: ios, emulation

Are there any emulators that run ipa (ios) files in either windows or mac?? I have an ipk file, and need I to check it on iPhones, iPads, and iPods. Thanks.

Comment: IPK? I have never heard of that file format. What is that for? Secondly, this community is for programmers, it seems to me that the right place for this question is http://superuser.com

Comment: Read this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator)

Comment: On windows it's NOT Possible But on mac in Simulator it's possible to some extent .