# trying to test ios app with xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I am a beginner and trying to understand how it is work (couldn't find answer on youtube). How can I test ios app using Xcode simulator? Lets say I want to test Facebook app using Xcode simulators. Do I need to have ipa or apa file or maybe some access to Xcode project?

Answer (score 1):

Testing an app on the iOS Simulator is normally part of the process of developing an app from source code. This is done from within Xcode, and is the default option when building and running an app. If are trying to run an app on the simulator in a situation where you do not have access to the source code but instead have an .ipa file, there are some [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator) which suggest you may be able to by taking a few extra steps. However, the .ipa file must contain an executable built for the macOS architecture (x86_64) and .ipa files typically do not contain this, as .ipa files are intended to run on iOS devices, not the simulator.

However this does not seem to be an intended workflow from Apple and may run afoul of the developer SDK agreement.