# Create .ipa file which should work on both real devices and Simulators

Tags: xcode, react-native

Right Now,
I am trying to use saucelab & testproject for application testing but for testing in simulators and real devices required to create a different .ipa file
which is too time consuming very time

So i want to generate .ipa file which should work on both simulator and physical device
My application is react-native based

Comment: you want to download via iTunes the ipa file ?

Comment: No i want create .ipa file of my developed application for mobile using react-native

Comment: ok do you know how to archive to get ipa in Xcode or should i drop an answer ?

Comment: @zeytin i know how to get .ipa file from archive but that .ipa file doesn't work on simulator i need a file that should work on both real and simulator ..

Comment: this is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/517463/14531220

Comment: i would say i want to create .ipa file which support both arm and i386 so i don't have to create separate .ipa file for each of them ...