# How to Install .ipa File on XCode iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, ios-simulator, ipa

I have downloaded an `.ipa` file from an iOS developer for our project.

I need to test the app on my simulator because I don't have a physical device, but I don't know how to.

**how to install the `.ipa` file to XCode iOS Simulator**? I have been read the difference between emulator and simulator, which the `.ipa` only able installed on real device and emulator while the `.app` only able installed on simulator. The emulator also mimic the real device's hardware and software while simulator only mimic the software and interface. If those differences above are true, does anyone know how to convert the `.ipa` to working `.app` file? I have been tried changed the `.ipa` to `.zip` by rename it then extract it and last, drag and drop the `.app` file (in the payload folder after extracted) to my simulator but failed, the message is "Please update the app". I also tried the command `xcrun simctl install` but failed. Currently, I am using the Mac with Big Sur and XCode 12. I can't download the project because the project size is very big and my internet too slow for download it, Thank you all

Comment: Please refer to this thread. Hope it is helpful. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator/51977478)

Comment: I have been refer to that thread before, So nothing that I can do, is it correct?

Comment: Please refer to this thread. Hope it is helpful. [How can I install a .ipa file to my iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator/51977478)

Comment: I have been refer to that thread before, So the only thing that I can do is get the Iphone as a testing device, it it correct?

Comment: They can create a simulator build and send it to you, but there is no way to run a device build on the simulator.  Even if you get a real device they will need to send you a new build because they will need to build including your device identifier

Comment: Oh no T_T, I will keep this thread open, who know Apple in the future have the solution for this and there are someone out there curious and have this same problem too, thank you all for your help and comment

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, and refer to that link before. it seems noway but to buy an iphone test device...

Answer (score -2):

Since you have the ability to run the simulator, You have the ability to have Xcode installed.

Rather than have the developer send you the IPA file, you could get access to the source code for your project (usually this is on a Git service provider) download the source and build the app to the simulator directly.

In a well set up project it shouldn't be hard to clone the repository, maybe run some configuration, then open Xcode and build to the simulator

Comment: Hi @Abizern, yeah currently we use this solution right now after Paulw's comment above for my question since it is more easier for my current situation. Thank you for answering Abizern